# Xsl: How can I Group and sort based on sum?

Tags: xslt

I have the below xml

```
 <ResultCollection>
  <Result Id="551550" Pass="23" Fail="0" Owner="Dong"/>
  <Result Id="551565" Pass="4" Fail="3" Owner="Dong"/>
  <Result Id="551567" Pass="61" Fail="0" Owner="Mei"/>
  <Result Id="551580" Pass="10" Fail="1" Owner="Dong"/>  
  <Result Id="551580" Pass="0" Fail="4" Owner="Sen"/>  
  <Result Id="551548" Pass="1" Fail="12" Owner="Sen"/>
</ResultCollection>
```

And I have an xsl that generates the below summary

```
Owner   Total   Pass    Fail
Dong    41  37  4
Mei     61  61  0
Sen     17  1   16
```

**How can I sort this result based on Pass or Fail?**

My xsl looks like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="FeatureOwner" match="Result" use="@Owner" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Result Summary</title>
        </head>
        <body>
                <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      <b>Owner</b></td>
                    <td>
                      <b>Total</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <b>Pass</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      <b>Fail</b>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <xsl:for-each select="ResultCollection/Result[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('FeatureOwner', @Owner)[1])]">
                    <xsl:variable name="varFeatureOwner">
                      <xsl:value-of select="@Owner" />
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="totFailures" select="sum(//ResultCollection/Result[@Owner=$varFeatureOwner]/@Fail)" />
                    <xsl:variable name="totPass" select="sum(//ResultCollection/Result[@Owner=$varFeatureOwner]/@Pass)" />
                    <xsl:variable name="total" select="$totPass+$totFailures" />
                     <tr>
                        <td>
                          <xsl:value-of select="$varFeatureOwner"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <xsl:value-of select="$total"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <xsl:value-of select="$totPass"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <xsl:value-of select="$totFailures"/>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
          </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The code is quite incomplete. Please, provide a complete, but minimum possible, working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Something like this** (*I have re-constructing your code, as it was missing quite a lot*):

**This XSLT transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:param name="pSortBy" select="'Pass'"/>

 <xsl:key name="kResultByOwner" match="Result"
  use="@Owner"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
            <xsl:for-each select=
            "ResultCollection/Result
                 [generate-id(.) 
                 = 
                  generate-id(key('kResultByOwner', @Owner)[1])
                  ]">
                 <xsl:sort data-type="number" select=
                "sum(key('kResultByOwner', @Owner)
                               /@*[name()=$pSortBy])"/> 

                <xsl:variable name="totFailures" select=
                "sum(/ResultCollection/Result
                          [@Owner=current()/@Owner]
                              /@Fail
               )" />
                <xsl:variable name="totPass" select=
                "sum(/ResultCollection/Result
                           [@Owner=current()/@Owner]
                              /@Pass
               )" />

                <xsl:variable name="total" select=
                   "$totPass+$totFailures" />
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current()/@Owner"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$total"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$totPass"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$totFailures"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the originally provided XML document**:

```
<ResultCollection>
    <Result Id="551550" Pass="23" Fail="0" Owner="Dong"/>
    <Result Id="551565" Pass="4" Fail="3" Owner="Dong"/>
    <Result Id="551567" Pass="61" Fail="0" Owner="Mei"/>
    <Result Id="551580" Pass="10" Fail="1" Owner="Dong"/>
    <Result Id="551580" Pass="0" Fail="4" Owner="Sen"/>
    <Result Id="551548" Pass="1" Fail="12" Owner="Sen"/>
</ResultCollection>
```

**produces the wanted result**):

```
Sen        17    1  16
Dong       41   37   4
Mei        61   61   0
```

**Do note the following**:

1. The summation of the values of the `@Pass` or the `@Fail` attribute for the elements that belong only to the current group (the use of the `key()` function).
2. The use of the `<xsl:sort .../>` instruction to sort by the required sums.
3. The use of a global parameter named `pSortBy`, which contains the name of the attribute on the sums of which to sort.
4. The use of the XSLT function `current()`