# Counting unique XML element attributes using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I've just started using XSLT and am trying to figure this out.
Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Example XML file

```
<purchases>
    <item id = "1" customer_id = "5">
    </item>
    <item id = "2" customer_id = "5">
    </item>
    <item id = "7" customer_id = "4">
    </item>
</purchases>
```

Desired HTML Output:

```
<table>
    <tr><th>Customer ID</th><th>Number of Items Purchased</th></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

Customer with id number 5 has bought 2 items.
Customer with id number 4 has bought 1 item.

Comment: Huh? Where do the 5 & 2 in the results come from? 2 is a count?

Comment: My mistake sorry.Thank you for pointing it out : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible Xslt 1.0 solution would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="kCustomer" match="item" use="@customer_id"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="purchases">
        <xsl:element name="table">
            <xsl:element name="tr">
                <xsl:element name="th">Customer ID</xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="th">Number of Items Purchased</xsl:element>
                <xsl:for-each select="item[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('kCustomer', @customer_id))]">
                    <xsl:variable name="total" select="count(/purchases/item[@customer_id=current()/@customer_id]/@id)" />
                    <xsl:element name="tr">
                        <xsl:element name="td">
                            <xsl:value-of select="./@customer_id" />
                        </xsl:element>
                        <xsl:element name="td">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$total" />
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Adopted from [Dimitres answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/758749/205233) on [How can I Group and sort based on sum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/758527/205233).

---

As pointed out by Dimitre the *purchases* template can be simplified to

```
    <xsl:template match="purchases">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Customer ID</th>
                <th>Number of Items Purchased</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="item[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('kCustomer', @customer_id))]">
                <xsl:variable name="total" select="count(/purchases/item[@customer_id=current()/@customer_id]/@id)" />
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="./@customer_id" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$total" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is good, but *why* are you using `xsl:element` and not literal-result elements? The code in its present form is much longer and quite difficult to read/understand.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I admit the use of `xsl:element` instead of mixing is just my personal preference. Using it in answers and examples here may have the benefit showing people new to Xslt how construct output. In this case my answers was meant as an complete alternative to Sean and merely an exercise for me since I had to refresh my knowledge from your answer.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: If your stylesheet is formatted nicely, then the output includes white space between literal-result elements; using pure `xsl:` elements prevents this. Although in this case, given the `indent="yes"` in the output method it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @Filburt: I strongly recommend using literal-result elements always when possible. Personal preferences shouldn't affect readability as the final result is for use of many thousands of people. As for constructing output, the first thing a novice has to learn is the simple use of literal-result elements.

Comment: @Flynn1179: Yes, you are absolutely right that `xsl:output indent="yes"` is a good formattiong solution -- better than using `xsl:element` for that purpose.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: My point is, using `<xsl:element>` means the output document is unformatted with no white space, and takes up less space, which is far preferable in a large document intended for downloading. As far as I'm aware, this isn't possible using literals in a well-formatted style sheet.

Comment: @Flynn1179: Why, using `indent="no"` serves exactly the purpose of conserving space. I have yet to see an example where you really need to use `xsl:element` for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT 1.0 solution ....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

      <xsl:template match="/">
        <table>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="purchases/item"/>     
        </table>
      </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="item">
     <xsl:if test="not(
       preceding-sibling::*[@customer_id=current()/@customer_id]
       )">     
         <tr><td><xsl:value-of select="@customer_id"/></td>
           <td><xsl:value-of select="count(following-sibling::item
             [@customer_id=current()/@customer_id])+1"/></td>
         </tr> 
     </xsl:if>   
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want XSLT 2.0 then the following XSLT should do the trick:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/purchases">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Customer ID</th>
                <th>Number of Items Purchased</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="item" group-by="@customer_id">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="count(current-group())"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I get header outputs but no data : (
Do you have an XSLT 1.0 solution?
Thank you for all your help and formatting my question  :)