# How to sort with highest average on top using xslt

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

My xml whit xsl i need to create a table where it should show average min and max. this i was able to to do. But I need to sort the table with highest average. How is this done?
Sample XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="simpleReport.xsl"?>
<Results>
    <Sample time="1797" prod="Val1" />
    <Sample time="919"  prod="Val2" />
    <Sample time="2680" prod="Val3" />
    <Sample time="545" prod="Val1" />
    <Sample time="520" prod="Val2" />
    <Sample time="1041" prod="Val3" />
    <Sample time="543" prod="Val1" />
    <Sample time="491" prod="Val2" />
    <Sample time="286" prod="Val3" />
    <Sample time="283" prod="Val1" />
    <Sample time="782" prod="Val2" />
    <Sample time="440" prod="Val2" />
</Results>
```

This is what i am doing for calculating average

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" />
<xsl:param    name="prodReport" select="'Results'"/>
<xsl:template match="Results">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title><xsl:value-of select="$prodReport" /></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:call-template name="ProductList" />
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="ProductList">
    <h2>Pages</h2>
    <table align="center" class="details" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="2" width="95%">
        <tr valign="top">
            <th>Sample</th>
            <th>Count</th>
            <th>Average Time</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Results/*[not(@prod = preceding::*/@prod)]">
            <xsl:variable name="prodName" select="@prod" />
            <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(../*[@prod = current()/@prod])" />
            <xsl:variable name="totalTime" select="sum(../*[@prod = current()/@prod]/@time)" />
            <xsl:variable name="averageTime" select="$totalTime div $count" />
            <tr valign="top">
                <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$prodName" />
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$count" />
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$averageTime" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How do sort based on computed average?
the HTML table columns would be ProdName Count AverageTime. where AverageTime would be in descending order.

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758527/xsl-how-can-i-group-and-sort-based-on-sum

Comment: Please include more of your stylesheet, together with the output XML (HTML) you expect.

Comment: I have update the my stylesheet. I went through the link but did not understand "sum(key('kResultByOwner', @Owner)/@*[name()=$pSortBy])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to sort by a variable. However, you can sort by the the expressions that you bound to the variables in question. Use the following expression as the first element in your `<xsl:for-each/>` expression:

```
<xsl:sort data-type="number" order="descending"
          select="sum(../*[@prod = current()/@prod]/@time) div
                  count(../*[@prod = current()/@prod])"/>
```

Comment: thanks this worked but could you please explain how is it that this statement knows which column to sort by? the statement does not seem to specify any column.

Comment: The path expression in the `select` attribute of the `<xsl:sort/>` element is evaluated relative to the context node, which is established by the `select` attribute of the `<xsl:for-each/>` element. This works exactly the same way as your existing variable bindings.